# Сравнение индексов в stl <vector>

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Мне нужно от минимального элемента вектора до максимального поменять знаки элементов на противоположные.

```
auto max =  *max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    cout << "Максимум " << max << endl;
    auto max = *min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    cout << "Минимум" << max << endl;
```

Дальше я хотела сравнить индексы этих элементов и сделать swap, если индекс максимального больше чем минимального. А дальше сделать цикл while (min!= max) arr*=-1
Был с вариантом for_each, но я не знаю как запихнуть в 3 параметр само действие.

В общем-то вопрос, как можно найти индексы этих элементов? Есть ли такая функция в STL?

Comment: Для вектора сработает даже простое вычитание `v.begin()` из найденного итератора... В общем случае - [`distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

Comment: Да вы издеваетесь? Это за неделю 3 раза вопрос, как между максимальным и минимальным поменять знаки. Что возвражиют min и max elem? Возвращают они итератор. Итератор по синтексису очень похож на указатель на конкретный элемент (у каждого контейнера свой итератор, у вектора это так). И в своём коде вы его разыменовываете. А что с указателями можно делать? Да что угодно! Сравнивать, отнимать от другого указателя, прибавлять и отнимать число. Собстенно `auto max =  max_element(v.begin(), v.end());` `auto min =  min_element(v.begin(), v.end());` дальше `if (min < max) swap (min, max);`

Comment: В for_each первые 2 переменные тоже итератор. `for_each(min, max, [](int &n){ n = - n; })`  [](int &n){ n = - n; } - лямбда функция. Можете загуглить, ничего сложного в ней нет.

Comment: https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/7.3.php - про итераторы, https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each - for_each с примером, https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp?view=vs-2019 - лямбды

Comment: так я так пыталась) Но у меня почему-то идет переопределение типов, если я под одной переменной разыменовываю, а под другой нет. Можно ли где-то посмотреть такие нюансы? auto maxIn = max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
 auto minIn = min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
 if (minIn < maxIn) swap(minIn, maxIn);
 for_each(minIn, maxIn, [](int &n) { return (n = -n); }); - вроде все подправила, но тут же вылезает ошибка, с которой я не сталкивалась "vector iterator range transposed"

Comment: эта ошибка из за того, что вы  меняете местами итераторы если  minIn < maxIn, т.е. если минимальный элемент идет раньше максимального. Тогда  minIn будет указывать на максимальный элемент, и получается, что вы пытаетесь идти с конца вперед, в for_each, что не соответствует требованиям алгоритма(нужно итерировать к концу)

Comment: Не ломайте себе голову поиском функций для очевидных вещей (и не воображайте, что они чудесным образом работают моментально). Пройдите в цикле по всем элементам и найдете за один проход искомые индексы.

Comment: if (max < min) swap(min, max);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto p = std::minmax_element(v.begin(), v.end());
std::cout << "positions:\nmin - "
          << std::distance(v.begin(), p.first) << '\n'
          << "max - "  << std::distance(v.begin(), p.second);
```

или

```
std::cout << "positions:\nmin - "
          <<  p.first - v.begin() << '\n'
          << "max - "  << p.second - v.begin();
```

**Обновление:**

это ответ на тот часть вопроса, где вы спрашиваете как получить индексы. Но в комментариях я понел, что вам нужно сделать это:

```
auto pmin = min_element(v.begin(), v.end()),
    pmax = max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
//вариант первый
if (pmin > pmax) //вы сравнивали неправильно
    swap(pmin, pmax);
while (++pmin != pmax)
    *pmin *= -1;
// вариант второй (в лямбде ничего не нужно возвращать)
for_each(std::min(pmin, pmax) + 1, std::max(pmin, pmax),
                                 [](int& i) { i = -i; });
```

можете смотреть результат:

```
for (int i : v)
cout << i << ' ';
```

Теперь ответ на вопросы в комментариях:

1. Во втором варианте применяем
       алгоритм  `for_each`, а этот алгоритм применяет функцию к каждому
       элементу последовательности (просто выполняет element = -element).
       Если возвращать из функции значение, это значение не будет
       использовано,  и будет безсмыссленное использование памяти. Есть
       другие алгоритмы(например transform), которые используют именно
       возвращаемое значение, но это не тот случай.
2. std::min(pmin, pmax) возвратит `pmin` или `pmax`, в зависимости от
   того, какой элемент встречается раньше_ (минимальный или
   максимальный), и  начинаем со следующего элемента(этот элемент
   пропускаем) применять функцию к элементам до `std::max(pmin, pmax)`,
   поэтому  к итератору `std::min(pmin, pmax)` применяем `operator+(1)`.
3. Мы не исключаем, что  индекс максимального может быть первее
   минимального, мы просто имеем два итератора, указывающие на
   элементы. Мы просто пишем программу так, чтобы первым итератором был
   именно тот, который содержит адрес элемента, который первее(не важно
   какой из них будет).

Для получения ответа на последный вопрос, лучше читайте  про цикл по коллекции

Comment: спасибо большое! Можете, пожалуйста, пояснить почему в лямбде не надо ничего возвращать? Мне скидывали ссылку выше,там был пример с возвращением. И зачем мы пишем +1? Не очень могу понять, как мы исключаем, что индекс максимального может быть первее минимального :( 1 вариант понятный, но хотелось бы разобраться со вторым. И правильно я поняла, что i : v - это краткое обозначение для всех i вектора v?

Comment: ответы на ваши вопросы в комментарий, я добавил в ответ. Если все понятно, и я помог вам, то нажмите галочку. Это поможет пользовательям понять, что вы решили свою проблему

Comment: а можете, пожалуйста, сказать название статьи, а то не открывается по ссылке

Comment: Elvis, C++11 - Википедия,  дальше пункт  2.3.4 For-цикл по коллекции